# Palavras que admitem dupla pronúncia

Tags: ortografia, fonemas

Nos exemplos a seguir, as palavras admitem dupla prosódia

> **Transistor** [tran-zis-**tôr** ou tran-**zís**-tor].
> Componente que foi criado para substituir a válvula eletrônica.
>
> **Projétil** [pro-**jé**-til ou pro-je-**til**].
> Algo que se pode arremessar.
>
> **Acrobata** [a-cro-**ba**-ta ou a-**cró**-ba-ta].
> O que salta ou faz exercícios ginásticos em corda ou equilibrista.

Por que isso ocorre?

É assim também em Portugual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fui ver a ocorrências destas palavras no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/). Apresento os números abaixo (os números incluem os plurais). *Acróbata*, vem em alguns dicionários, mas não aparece no Corpus, nem em Portugal nem no Brasil. *Projetil* só se usa no Brasil, e mesmo aí *projétil* é mais usado. Depois, basicamente o Brasil usa *transistor* e Portugal *transístor*. Fiquei surpreendido com as dez ocorrências de *transitor* em Portugal, porque nunca ouvi a palavra pronunciada assim.

```
           acróbata/acrobata    projé(c)til/proje(c)til    transístor/transitor
Brasil           0 / 71                 70 / 32                    1 / 44
Portugal         0 / 15                 61 / 0                    35 / 10
```

Quando à razão da existência de duas formas, penso que se poderá passar o seguinte. Estas três palavras têm algumas coisas em comum: são de origem estrangeira e são relativamente recentes no português. Ênfase no *relativamente*. Segundo o dicionário Houaiss, *acrobata* é conhecido desde 1783; *projétil/projetil*, desde 1789; e *transístor/transitor*, desde 1948 (a coisa foi inventada em 1947).

Ora quando se importa uma palavra estrangeira, esta tem de ser adaptada ao português, e parece-me natural que uns a adaptem de uma maneira, e outros, de outra. Por exemplo, há o caso da palavra *performance*, que também é relativamente recente e ainda aparece nos dicionários como palavra estrangeira. Eu lembro-me de no fim dos anos oitenta e anos noventa ouvir algumas pessoas, creio que a maioria, pôr a tónica no *for* e outros no *man*. Não havendo referenciais na língua para essas palavras, não me surpreende que os falantes não concordem prontamente numa forma única. Depois o facto de o português já estar estabelecido no Brasil e Portugal quando as palavras integraram a língua facilitou que vingassem formas diferentes nos dois países, como foi basicamente o caso de *transístor* e *transistor*.

Comment: Tive várias cadeiras no dpto de eng. eletrotécnica e nunca na vida ouvi _transistor_, como oxítona... Suponho que simplesmente a escrita demorou a estabilizar.

Answer (score 5):

Em Portugal só se escreve (e se diz) *transístor*. *Transistor* é uma grafia brasileira, o que indica que por esse lados a palavra é (também) paroxítona. O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/trans%C3%ADstor) lista ambas as grafias (e ambas as pronúncias).

O mesmo se passa com *projétil*. Em Portugal, a única forma é com acento: *projétil* e assim se pronuncia, como paroxítona. No Brasil ambas as grafias estão registadas no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/proj%C3%A9til), com uma nota indicando que *projétil* é mais comum em Portugal.

Quanto a *acrobata*, repare-se que todas as palavras proparoxítonas têm de ser acentuadas. Não o sendo *acrobata*, a sílaba tónica não pode ser a antepenúltima sílaba. Em Portugal, a palavra só se pronuncia como paroxítona (e só se escreve sem acento). Embora o Aulete não registe a forma *acróbata*, o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/acrobata%20_894169.html) fá-lo. Portanto essa variante parece ter alguma aceitação.